# remove rows including and after a string

Tags: r, plyr

say we have:

```
dat <-  data.frame( x1 = c(rep(c("A","B"), each = 4),"B"),
                x2 = rep(c("a","a","b","b", "a","a","a","a","a")),
                x3 = c("cow","pig","cow","cow",
                       "cow","pig","pig","pig",
                       "cow"
                       )
                  )
```

I want to keep for every x1:x2 combination all the rows before "pig" occurs and remove all rows after including and after "pig" occurs.

If there is only "cow" then I keep all "cows", if there is only "pig" then remove all rows.

This example would give:

```
  x1 x2  x3
1  A  a cow
3  A  b cow
4  A  b cow
5  B  a cow
```

I can write the ddply for example fine for this, but i know there must be a function to to quickly get rows prior to "pig" that I cannot find and save a loop.

Comment: I think you want to fix your example: you've got "pig" in row 2 but you allowed cows after that row. Please review.

Comment: yes but the pig in row 2 refers to A:a not A:b (i.e. x1:x2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier with subsetting:

```
 dat[!(dat$x3=='pig'),]
 x1 x2  x3
1  A  a cow
3  A  b cow
4  A  b cow
```

EDIT: to remove all rows after the first 'pig', do this:

```
badrow<-which(dat$x3=='pig')[1]
dat[1:(badrow-1),]
```

with some added code to handle cases where `which` returns nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks Carl I think perhaps my example was insufficient, e.g. if for A:a I had cow,pig,cow   your solution would keep the second cow no? I edited my example to cover this.

Comment: I think i can work from here, this for instance doesn't take care of cases where pig does not exist, cheers carl